# Replace parameter in lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, partial-application

Considering this code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
}

private void Test()
{
    List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
    foos.Add(new Foo());
    foos.Add(new Foo());
    Expression<Func<Foo, int>> exp0 = f => f.a * f.b;
    Expression<Func<int>> exp1 = () => foos[0].a * foos[0].b;
    Expression<Func<int>> exp2 = () => foos[1].a * foos[1].b;
}
```

How can you take `exp0` and turn it into two expressions identical to `exp1` and `exp2`. Note that I don't want to just evaluate `exp0` for each `Foo` in `foos`, but instead get two new expressions.

**[Update]**:

Basically, I want to be able to expand or "flatten" an expression passed to a `Linq` extension method such as `Sum` into one expression per item in the enumeration since these enumerations will be static, and because I already have code that reads expressions that don't take parameters (and then turns them into another language).

I'm using the `MetadataToken` as a references to properties that have a certain attribute (in this case `a` and `b` would have this attribute) and using it with a dictionary that correlates C# properties to another language's variables:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Expression<Func<int>> exp = () => foo.a * foo.a + foo.b;
string result1 = GetResult(exp); // gets "v_001 * v_001 + v_002"

List<Foo> foes = new List<Foo>();
foes.Add(new Foo());
foes.Add(new Foo());
Expression<Func<int>> exp2 = () => foes.Sum(f => f.a * f.a + f.b);
string result2 = GetResult(exp2); // should get "(v_001 * v_001 + v_002) + (v_003 * v_003 + v_004)"
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you would use this and what the output would be?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631070/currying-expressions-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would do it this way:

Write a parameter-replacer expression-visitor that manipulates the original expression as follows:

1. Gets rid of the parameter you don't want entirely from the lambda signature.
2. Replaces all uses of the parameter with the desired indexer expression.

Here's a quick and dirty sample I whipped up based on my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7051745/412770) on a different question:

```
public static class ParameterReplacer
{
    // Produces an expression identical to 'expression'
    // except with 'source' parameter replaced with 'target' expression.     
    public static Expression<TOutput> Replace<TInput, TOutput>
                    (Expression<TInput> expression,
                    ParameterExpression source,
                    Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacerVisitor<TOutput>(source, target)
                    .VisitAndConvert(expression);
    }

    private class ParameterReplacerVisitor<TOutput> : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private ParameterExpression _source;
        private Expression _target;

        public ParameterReplacerVisitor
                (ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
        {
            _source = source;
            _target = target;
        }

        internal Expression<TOutput> VisitAndConvert<T>(Expression<T> root)
        {
            return (Expression<TOutput>)VisitLambda(root);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
        {
            // Leave all parameters alone except the one we want to replace.
            var parameters = node.Parameters
                                 .Where(p => p != _source);

            return Expression.Lambda<TOutput>(Visit(node.Body), parameters);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            // Replace the source with the target, visit other params as usual.
            return node == _source ? _target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage for your scenario (tested):

```
var zeroIndexIndexer = Expression.MakeIndex
        (Expression.Constant(foos),
         typeof(List<Foo>).GetProperty("Item"), 
         new[] { Expression.Constant(0) });


// .ToString() of the below looks like the following: 
//  () =>    (value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[App.Foo]).Item[0].a
//         *  value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[App.Foo]).Item[0].b)
var exp1Clone = ParameterReplacer.Replace<Func<Foo, int>, Func<int>>
                  (exp0, exp0.Parameters.Single(), zeroIndexIndexer);
```

Comment: For nested lambdas, I found I must use Expression.Lambda(...) instead of Expression.Lambda<TOutput>(...).  The type parameter version seems unnecessary in any case.