# remove a condition from ef expression tree

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework to handle the database in a MVC application: I created a search engine for the application using several fields from start form, and setting privileges that comes from the user role, so the routine that create the select statement is growing, so sometimes I have this situation.
before i make a selection:

1. var orders = db.Orders.Where( ord => ord.Channel == 1 || ord.Channel == 2);

   after in the source code, in some cases, type of users, filter combinations, and so on, I have to change this filter or remove this condition
2. orders = db.Orders.Where( ord => ord.Channel == 1 );

   this is just a simple example, because doing this way i loose the other filters I have done in the Linq expression tree, and cause i have request to add features very often, it's very difficult to reorganize all the code to test all the prerequisite before to add conditions to the expression tree so i would like to know if is possible to remove a statement in the linq expression tree after has been added and before the tree is parsed and converted in a sql query

luca

Comment: Have you thought about using the `.Contains()` method? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, I believe the simplest possible approach is to defer the creation of the query until you have collected all the data needed to know what the query should look like, i.e. in this case it would mean you build the query only after you already know whether the condition actually needs to be applied.

If it is not possible for you to defer the creation of the query (it seems to me that is what you are saying), but you can still anticipate which conditions may need to be removed at a later point, I would consider introducing a Boolean sentinel in the query, e.g. based on your query snippet:

```
var orders = db.Orders.Where( ord => 
    (isFirstConditionRelevant && ord.Channel == 1) 
    || (isSecondConditionRelvant && ord.Channel == 2));
```

The variables 'isFirstConditionRelevant' and 'isSecondConditionRelevant' would be initially be set to true and would be captured by the query expression, but you could set to false at a later point (e.g. just before executing the query) if you needed the corresponding condition to have no effect. Notice that with this approach the SQL translation of the query will still contain the condition, but it will also contain a parameter for each sentinel that will short circuit the Boolean logic when the query is executed by the server.

Note also that any constants in your conditions (e.g. the '1' in 'ord.Channel == 1') will be translated to constant in the SQL. I would suggest using variables as this will introduce parameters in the SQL query that could increase the chances that the query plan can be reused on the server.

Another approach that could be useful is to take advantage of support for references to expression variables in the query, e.g. you could pass a variable of type Expression> to the Where clause and at a later point replace the value of the variable to the right predicate. If I remember correctly, LINQ to Entities supports using expression variables as predicate conditions over nested collections by applying the AsQueryable operator to the collection in the query. Otherwise you can take advantage of the support for AsExpandable in provided by the LINQ kit. You will find more information about this, as well as examples of using references to expression variables in the LINQ Kit home page: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx.

The fourth and most complicated approach I would consider is to use my own visitor (e.g. derived from System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor) to rewrite the LINQ expression tree (in this case to remove the condition from the predicate) before the query is executed. I don't have an expression visitor that does exactly that handy. Instead, I can provide a few pointers to articles that solve different parts of the problem:

1. This thread in StackOverflow describes how to use an expression visitor to do some query rewriting: [Using a LINQ ExpressionVisitor to replace primitive parameters with property references in a lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164009/using-a-linq-expressionvisitor-to-replace-primitive-parameters-with-property-ref).
2. This great blog post by Alex James describes how to write an intercepting query provider that will call your expression rewriting visitor just be fore the query is executed: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/03/01/tip-55-how-to-extend-an-iqueryable-by-wrapping-it.aspx.
3. The following article describes a library that can be used to rewrite expressions based on rules: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24454/Modifying-LINQ-Expressions-with-Rewrite-Rules.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really helpful answer. Congrats.