# Get MethodInfo from Expression tree

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I have the following method:

```
public TResult Call<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> code)
{
    var returnValue = default(TResult);
    // code that will inspect the interface method that is being called 
    // along with lots of other code
    // and then call a WebAPI service.
    return returnValue;
}
```

In this instance, `T` is an interface named `ICustomer` and `TResult` will be a class `CustomerData`
In this specific instance, I'm doing the following:

```
var model = client.Call(customer => customer.Get(1));
```

My ultimate goal with this is to be able to inspect the interface method for certain attributes. Based on those attributes, I'd like to call a WebAPI service and pass to it any parameters that were in the interface method.

How do I figure out in the `Call` method that the `interface.Get(1)` method was called?

Comment: You should put some type constraints on T and TResult if they're always going to be those types.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer they won't always be those types. I went ahead and updated the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

After fooling around, All I needed to do was cast the `Body` of the expression as `MethodCallExpression`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `ExpressionVisitor` for this. Overriding [`VisitMethodCall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.visitinvocation(v=vs.110).aspx) method will let you examine each method call inside the expression. In case of `customer => customer.Get(1)` you would get a single callback with [`MethodCallExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) with `Object` property set to `ParameterExpression` representing `customer`, `Method` parameter set to `MethodInfo` of the `Get` method, and `Arguments` set to a collection of a single constant expression representing integer constant `1`.

Comment: I'm not able to override `VisitMethodCall`. It's protected. The only thin you're able to override is `Visit`.

Comment: You can override protected methods in inheritor class. .Net allows to do such things

Comment: @JustinAdkins It shouldn't be an issue - take a look at [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11164009/335858) for an example.