# Expression.Block method gives different errors in c#

Tags: expression, block

Let us have the following:

```
Func<string, int> counterOfChar = (myString) => {
         Console.WriteLine("Here is my parameter "+myString); 
         return myString.Count();
};
```

I want to bring all expressions involved here , by defining them so:

```
Expression<Action<string>> first = (param) => Console.WriteLine("Here is my parameter "+param);
Expression<Func<string, int>> second = (param) => param.Count();
```

And then call `Expression.Block(first, second);` as an example .

I am struggling for a week now and I don't want to tell you how diverse are the errors received until this moment. 
Can someone write the corresponding Block and lambda expression for the delegate, but not going deep into ex: Method.Call ? Just stick to expressions !?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Expression<Action<string>> first = (param) => Console.WriteLine("Here is my parameter " + param);
Expression<Func<string, int>> second = (param) => param.Length; // .Count() is useless here!

Expression<Func<string, int>> third = 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<string, int>>(
         Expression.Block(first.Body, 
                          Expression.Invoke(second, first.Parameters[0])), 
         first.Parameters[0]);

var f = third.Compile();
var r1 = f("Hello");
```

"merging" two Expressions is always a little complex, because the two `param` of the two expressions are "different". They aren't the same `param` (it's like one is `param1` and the other is `param2`). Here we resolve it by reusing the first parameter of the first expression as the parameter of the "new" expression and `Expression.Invoke` the other expression.

Without cheating, we could have

```
var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));

Expression<Func<string, int>> third = 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<string, int>>(
        Expression.Block(
            Expression.Invoke(first, par), 
            Expression.Invoke(second, par)), 
        par);

var f = third.Compile();
var r1 = f("Hello");
```

where we introduce a new parameter `par` and we `Expression.Invoke` the other two expressions.

Note that Entity Framework doesn't support `Expression.Invoke`. In this case you can use a parameter rewriter (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11160067/613130).)

Comment: It says here to avoid comments as : Thanks...etc .

Comment: I have marked as an answer but i can't upvote , I need more reputation. The answer is exactly what i needed.