# Replace parameter type in lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expressionvisitor

I am trying to replace the parameter type in a lambda expression from one type to another.

I have found other answers on stackoverflow i.e. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159697/replace-parameter-in-lambda-expression) but I have had no luck with them.

Imagine for a second you have a domain object and a repository from which you can retrieve the domain object.

however the repository has to deal with its own Data transfer objects and then map and return domain objects:

ColourDto.cs

```
public class DtoColour {

    public DtoColour(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

DomainColour.cs

```
public class DomainColour {

    public DomainColour(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Repository.cs

```
public class ColourRepository {
    ...
    public IEnumerable<DomainColour> GetWhere(Expression<Func<DomainColour, bool>> predicate)
    {
        // Context.Colours is of type ColourDto
        return Context.Colours.Where(predicate).Map().ToList();
    }
}
```

As you can see this will not work as the predicate is for the domain model and the Collection inside the repository is a collection of Data transfer objects.

I have tried to use an `ExpressionVisitor` to do this but cannot figure out how to just change the type of the `ParameterExpression` without an exception being thrown for example:

Test scenario

```
public class ColourRepository {
    ...
    public IEnumerable<DomainColour> GetWhere(Expression<Func<DomainColour, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var visitor = new MyExpressionVisitor();
        var newPredicate = visitor.Visit(predicate) as Expression<Func<ColourDto, bool>>;
        return Context.Colours.Where(newPredicate.Complie()).Map().ToList();
    }
}


public class MyExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return Expression.Parameter(typeof(ColourDto), node.Name);
    }
}
```

finally here is the exception:

> System.ArgumentException : Property 'System.String Name' is not
>   defined for type 'ColourDto'

Hope someone can help.

**EDIT: Here is a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LQ6XE9)**

still doesnt work.

**Edit: Here is a working [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HlZgPX)**

Thanks [Eli Arbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276083/eli-arbel)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to do a few things for this to work:

- Replace parameter instance both at the `Expression.Lambda` and anywhere they appear in the body - and use the same instance for both.
- Change the lambda's delegate type.
- Replace the property expressions.

Here's the code, with added generics:

```
public static Func<TTarget, bool> Convert<TSource, TTarget>(Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> root)
{
    var visitor = new ParameterTypeVisitor<TSource, TTarget>();
    var expression = (Expression<Func<TTarget, bool>>)visitor.Visit(root);
    return expression.Compile();
}

public class ParameterTypeVisitor<TSource, TTarget> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression> _parameters;

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return _parameters?.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == node.Name) ?? 
            (node.Type == typeof(TSource) ? Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTarget), node.Name) : node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        _parameters = VisitAndConvert<ParameterExpression>(node.Parameters, "VisitLambda");
        return Expression.Lambda(Visit(node.Body), _parameters);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(TSource))
        {
            return Expression.Property(Visit(node.Expression), node.Member.Name);
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tweeked the VisitMember override to use MakeMemberAccess: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HlZgPX

Comment: @Eli Arbel thanks to your code I'm able to convert a Expression<Func<T, bool>> in Expression<Func<object, bool>> but if my source expression is "x => x.MyProp == 2" I get an runtime error "ArgumentException: Instance property 'MyProp' is not defined for type 'System.Object' (Parameter 'propertyName')"; how can I add a cast during conversion? Thanks

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm dumb but I thought that one could use different instances of a `ParameterExpression` as long as it had the same name and type, and I had problems with it. So it is very important to use **the same** instance of the `ParameterExpression` we want to replace everywhere in the visitor, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Properties are defined separately for each type.

That error happens because you can't get the value of a property defined by `DomainColour` from a value of type `ColourDto`.

You need to visit every `MemberExpression` that uses the parameter and return a new `MemberExpression` that uses that property from the new type.

Comment: Do you have an example for the scenario above?

Answer (score 0):

The Eli's answer is great.

But in my case, I have a lambda which have another lambda inside it. So, it sets the '_parameter' twice, overriding the old.

ex:

```cs
Expression<Func<IObjectWithCompanyUnits, bool>> expr = e => e.CompanyUnits.Any(cu => cu.ID == GetCurrentCompanyUnitId());
```

The Visitor breaks the expression above.

So I tweaked the original answer to my case:

```cs
public class ParameterTypeVisitor<TSource, TTarget> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private Dictionary<int, ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression>> _parameters = new();

    private int currentLambdaIndex = -1;

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        var prms = _parameters.Count > currentLambdaIndex ? _parameters[currentLambdaIndex] : null;

        var p = prms?.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == node.Name);
        if (p != null)
        {
            return p;
        }
        else
        {
            if (node.Type == typeof(TSource))
            {
                return Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTarget), node.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                return node;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        currentLambdaIndex++;
        try
        {
            _parameters[currentLambdaIndex] = VisitAndConvert<ParameterExpression>(node.Parameters, "VisitLambda");
            return Expression.Lambda(Visit(node.Body), _parameters[currentLambdaIndex]);
        }
        finally
        {
            currentLambdaIndex--;
        }
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(TSource))
        {
            return Expression.Property(Visit(node.Expression), node.Member.Name);
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```