# C# Expression.Property of an interface

Tags: c#, expression

I was generating a dynamic expression on CustomType based on some parameters. Code looks like this:

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CustomType), "x");
MemberExpression idMember = Expression.Property(parameter, "CustomProperty");
```

When I changed from type CustomType to interface ICustomType it stopped working by throwing an error 'Instance property 'CustomProperty' is not defined for type 'ICustomType''
. How to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you give more details about exactly what you mean by "it stopped working"? A [mcve] would be really helpful here.

Comment: Why would a parameter be enumerable? It is unusual for a parameter to be a list objects.

Comment: @jdweng I have IQueryable<ICustomType>, which represents a query on the database.

Comment: I think I got error, because I've used interface as IQueryable<ICustomType> customFunction(), not as IQueryable<T> customFunction<T>() where T:class, ICustomClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a minimum verifiable example, we cannot be sure what the problem is, but from your example code, I've put together the following:

```
interface ICustomType
{
    int CustomProperty { get; set; }
}

class CustomType : ICustomType
{
    public int CustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I call your example code, everything works as expected

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CustomType), "x");
MemberExpression idMember = Expression.Property(parameter, "CustomProperty");
```

Also, when I change the type to `ICustomType`, it **still** works as expected.

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ICustomType), "x");
MemberExpression idMember = Expression.Property(parameter, "CustomProperty");
```

However, if I remove the declaration of `CustomProperty` from `ICustomType`, I get the following error:

> Instance property 'CustomProperty' is not defined for type 'ICustomType'

So, this leads me to believe that your interface does not include a declaration for `CustomProperty`.  If you add it to your interface, your code should then work.

Answer (score 0):

A common task when working with expressions is to replace certain nodes with other nodes. For instance, you can replace `ParameterExpression` as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11160067/419761). I believe the OP used a similar parameter replacer, and forgot to also replace `MemberExpression`.

If you replace parameters of an expression, the original `MemberExpression` might not the new parameter type. E.g. a member expression for `CustomType.CustomProperty` will not be able to handle `ICustomType.CustomProperty`.

If my theory is correct, the OP must replace some `MemberExpression` instances too. The following expression visitor will do the trick:

```cs
public class ParameterReplacerVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Type newType;
    private Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> parametersToReplace;

    public ParameterReplacerVisitor(Type newType)
    {
        this.newType = newType;
    }

    public LambdaExpression Convert(LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        parametersToReplace = expression.Parameters
            .Where(p => ShouldReplace(p.Type))
            .ToDictionary(p => p, p => Expression.Parameter(newType, p.Name));

        return (LambdaExpression)Visit(expression);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        var parameters = node.Parameters.Select(GetNewParameter);
        return Expression.Lambda(Visit(node.Body), parameters);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return base.VisitParameter(GetNewParameter(node));
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (ShouldReplace(node.Member.DeclaringType))
        {
            var targetProperty = GetNewProperty(node.Member);
            node = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Visit(node.Expression), targetProperty);
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    private MemberInfo GetNewProperty(MemberInfo member)
    {
        return newType.GetProperty(member.Name) ?? throw new ArgumentException(
            $"Property '{member.Name}' is not defined for type '{newType.Name}'"
        );
    }

    private bool ShouldReplace(Type type) => newType.IsAssignableFrom(type);

    private ParameterExpression GetNewParameter(ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        parametersToReplace.TryGetValue(parameter, out var newParameter);
        return newParameter ?? parameter;
    }
}
```

### Example

```cs
Expression<Func<Derived, string>> derived = t => t.A;
var lessDerived = derived.ToLessDerived<Derived, IBase, string>();
var d = lessDerived.Compile();
var result = d.Invoke(new Base());
```

And the extension method:

```cs
public static Expression<Func<TLess, TValue>> ToLessDerived<TClass, TLess, TValue>(this Expression<Func<TClass, TValue>> expression)
{
    var visitor = new ParameterReplacerVisitor(typeof(TLess));
    return (Expression<Func<TLess, TValue>>)visitor.Convert(expression);
}
```

For me, this solved the exact same type of error as the OP asked about.